# ParentFragmentManager and ChildFragmentManager give wrong behavior

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-alertdialog, fragmentmanager

I have a fragment that is one of the many children of parent fragment. Also, I have an instance of custom alert dialog that is called through method show(FragmentManager, tag).

The thing is that I can't achieve the desired behavior when alert dialog appears above current fragment. If I use getParentFragmentManager or getSupportFragmentManager it opens above that parent fragment that is up in the hierarchy, when I use getChildFragmentManageк it shows for a sec and disappears.

I am almost lost having tried all the stuff I came across. Will be extremely grateful for any help.

This is a cut of my custom alert dialog

```
public class CustomAlertDialog extends BaseDialogFragment {
    private AlertdialogBinding mBinding;
    private final OnDialogClickListener mDialogClickListener;

    public CustomAlertDialog (OnDialogClickListener listener) {
        mDialogClickListener = listener;
    }

    public interface OnDialogClickListener {
        void onPositiveClick(CustomAlertDialog dialog);

        void onNegativeClick(CustomAlertDialog dialog);

        void onClick(CustomAlertDialog dialog, int which);

    }

    public static CustomAlertDialog newInstance(String title, String message, Boolean positive, Boolean negative, OnDialogClickListener listener) {
        CustomAlertDialog fragment = new CustomAlertDialog(listener);
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ALERT_DIALOG_TITLE_KEY, title);
        args.putString(ALERT_DIALOG_MESSAGE_KEY, message);
        args.putBoolean(ALERT_DIALOG_BUTTON_OK_KEY, positive);
        args.putBoolean(ALERT_DIALOG_BUTTON_CANCEL_KEY, positive);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }
```

And this is how I call it from my fragment that is a child of parent fragment

```
 CustomAlertDialog customAlertDialog  = CustomAlertDialog.newInstance(getResources().getString(R.string.dialog_title), getResources().getString(R.string.alert), true, false, new CustomAlertDialog.OnDialogClickListener() {

                                @Override
                                public void onPositiveClick(CustomAlertDialog dialog) {
                                    return;
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onNegativeClick(CustomAlertDialog  dialog) {

                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onClick(CustomAlertDialog  dialog, int which) {

                                }
                            });
                            customAlertDialog .show(getParentFragmentManager(), "dialog");}
```

How can I achieve my dialog be above current fragment from where I call it?

Comment: What is `BaseDialogFragment` please post code

Comment: Where are  you calling it?

Comment: @KishoreJethava posted, thank you

Comment: @Sajjad I'm calling it from my fragment onCreateView method

Answer (score 0):

Try using `getParentFragment().getParentFragmentManager()`

Comment: thank you, but this gives the same behavior as getParentFragmentManager()

Comment: Please explain why/how your code solves the OP's issue.

Comment: I once did a project with fragments inside a parent viewpager fragment and was required to use this code for proper behaviour. As OP mentioned, he also had fragment inside a fragment, so I thought this might solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

In one of the comments you wrote that you are calling your dialog from onCreateView. I am not sure, but i think calling it in onViewCreated is the right method to call your dialog

```
     @Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
CustomAlertDialog customAlertDialog  = CustomAlertDialog.newInstance(getResources().getString(R.string.dialog_title), getResources().getString(R.string.alert), true, false, new CustomAlertDialog.OnDialogClickListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onPositiveClick(CustomAlertDialog dialog) {
                                return;
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onNegativeClick(CustomAlertDialog  dialog) {

                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onClick(CustomAlertDialog  dialog, int which) {

                            }
                        });
                        customAlertDialog .show(getParentFragmentManager(), "dialog");}
```

}